# Can't get rid of GPG-error: http://download.opensuse.org

Tags: apt, keyserver

I have been googling for hours trying to find a way to get rid of the annoying gpg-error referring to the link below.

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org Release: The following signatures could not be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9A5EED8CBCA00D90
```

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 9A5EED8CBCA00D90
```

but to no avail.

Google Translated error message:

> The following signatures could not be verified because the public key is not available

Comment: Please translate the error message...

Comment: I don't see why openSUSE keys should be in the Ubuntu keyserver. Look through the openSUSE documentation, I'm sure they'll have steps to get the key.

Comment: W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org Release: The following signatures could not be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9A5EED8CBCA00D90

Comment: @EliahKagan: I have looked at the suggested duplicate and tried everything there, but it has not helped.

Comment: @muru: I don't know where opensuse comes from. Must be related to some package I have installed, but I have not been able to find which. I am not sure it is even needed by anything I am using or if it is a leftover from some previous install that I have removed.

Comment: Then comment out the opensuse entry from your sources and try again. You'll find out quickly enough whether you need it or not.

Comment: @muru: Problem is I don't know which source I should edit or how to find it. I have just gone through all answers to http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey but error persists.

Comment: Finding it is easy: `grep -i opensuse /etc/apt/sources.list*`

Comment: Aah, thanks! I found the culprits in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/trojita-nightly.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/trojita-nightly.list.save, so I removed both files and now the error is gone.

Comment: Because you're specifically trying to use the `trojita` package, here's some useful information: https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:jkt-gentoo:trojita&package=trojita
Basically, for Ubuntu 16.04:
`sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jkt-gentoo:/trojita/xUbuntu_16.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:jkt-gentoo:trojita.list" \
wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:jkt-gentoo:trojita/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.key -O Release.key \
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key \
sudo apt-get update \
sudo apt-get install trojita`

Answer (score 17):

If you don't need the source, you can look up and remove/comment the source entries. To find out where they are:

```
grep -iR opensuse /etc/apt/sources.list*
```

In all likelihood, they are in the `sources.list.d` folder, so this command should disable such entries:

```
sudo sed -i '/opensuse/ s/^/#/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

You can ignore files with the `.save` extension.